# Unable to make my app location aware

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, location-aware

I am following the android tutorial on making your app location aware [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
but when I run it in the emulator the below method

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("state", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}
```

shows in the Logcat:

> Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 9

Does anyone know what ErrorCode 9 means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `public static final int SERVICE_INVALID`
>
> The version of the Google Play services installed on this device is
>   not authentic.
>
> Constant Value: 9

Source: [ConnectionResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html)

Are you running the emulator that uses the Google APIs?

Comment: Thanks, I had to update the emulator to a target version of android that includes google API's. Now it works.